# Send checkbox Name, Value and GroupName to a method OnClick

Tags: vba, vbscript, excel, checkbox

I'm currently trying to call a Sub within the onclick event of a checkbox. What I want to do is grab the groupName, Name and Value parameters of the checkbox that I have clicked and feed them into a sub which uses the variables to toggle the rest of the checkboxes in the group to be hidden or unhidden. However, there are multiple group checkboxes that I want to have the same functionality and rather than create multiple functions for each onclick event I want to just be able to call the sub which processes the change in visibility each time.

[image: Application example]

Consider the image above. If I set the 'Admin' checkbox to be false the 'Old versions' checkbox within the same box should be hidden. If I check it to true, it should be shown again. I also want to do the same with the client box. I've looked online and many people recommend using ActiveControl.Value or Application.Caller but none of these seem to work. The two subs I am using so far can be found below. In it's current state, the application errors at

```
    admin_value = ActiveControl.Value
```

Here is the full code snippet:

```
  Private Sub admin_toggle_Click()

      Dim admin_group As String
      Dim admin_name As String
      Dim admin_value As String

      admin_value = ActiveControl.Value
      admin_name = ActiveControl.Name
      admin_group = ActiveControl.GroupName

     Call toggle_options

  End Sub

  Private Sub toggle_options()

  Dim ctl As Control

  For Each ctl In Me.Controls

    If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
        If ctl.GroupName = admin_group Then
        If ctl.Name <> admin_name Then
            If admin_value = True Then
            ctl.Visible = True
            Else
            ctl.Visible = False
            End If
        End If
        End If
    End If

Next ctl

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub admin_toggle_Click()
    Dim ctl As Control

    Set ctl = admin_frame.ActiveControl
    ShowHideControls admin_frame, ctl
End Sub

Sub ShowHideControls(frme As Control, cb As Control)
    Dim c As Control

    For Each c In frme.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
            If c.Name <> cb.Name Then
                If cb.Value = True Then
                    c.Visible = True
                Else
                    c.Visible = False
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Siddharth i'm afraid that's not what I need at all. That would involve me having to repeat a lot of code in each of the toggle checkboxes when I should really be able to call one function from each one saving numerous lines of code. The main part I am struggling with is grabbing the value of the selected checkbox and assigning it to a variable.

Comment: Also I wish to hide the subcategory checkboxes rather than select or deselect them.

Comment: Yes but I must be able to pass the value, name and groupname of the control which was clicked to the Sub so that it processes and hides/shows the checkboxes that are related to each master checkbox.

Comment: BTW when you say group name, do you mean the FRAME?

Comment: Thanks Siddharth. You are a legend! I actually wanted to refer to them by group name but as they are all encased within the same frame the solution above makes more sense. By groupName I actually meant the groupName parameter that you can apply to controls.